# How to filter your list based on datetime?

Tags: python, list, datetime, for-loop, min

This is my list:

```
matched_rows_2 =[
    ['1', '07-09-2020', '8:43:02', '100', 'TTF'],
    ['2', '07-09-2020', '8:43:02', '100', 'GGY'],
    ['3', '07-09-2020', '7:53:08', '120', 'HHJ'],
    ['4', '07-09-2020', '7:54:01', '160', 'JJH'],
    ['5', '07-09-2020', '8:30:00', '160', 'RRT'],
    ['6', '07-09-2020', '10:10:10', '160', 'PPO'],
    ['7', '07-09-2020', '11:12:11', '100', 'KKG'],
    ['8', '07-09-2020', '11:31:55', '160', 'PPO']]
```

**Im trying to do the following:**

1. For every vehicle number (`index[3]`), I'm trying to get the list which has a datetime that is the closest to `chosen_datetime`.

I've tried multiple things, but it doesnt seem to work yet. **Below is my cod**e:

```
chosen_datetime = datetime.fromisoformat("2020-07-09 08:43:55+00:00")
dts = [datetime.strptime(sub[1] + ' ' + sub[2], "%d-%m-%Y  %H:%M:%S").replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc) for sub in matched_rows_2]

for x in matched_rows_2:
    closest_to_chosen_datetime = min(dts, key=lambda d: max( d, chosen_datetime) - min(d, chosen_datetime))
    if closest_to_chosen_datetime:
        print(x)
```

**This is my desired output:**

```
['1', '07-09-2020', '8:43:02', '100', 'TTF'],
['2', '07-09-2020', '8:43:02', '100', 'GGY'],
['3', '07-09-2020', '7:53:08', '120', 'HHJ'],
['5', '07-09-2020', '8:30:00', '160', 'RRT'],
```

**This is my current output:**

```
['1', '07-09-2020', '8:43:02', '100', 'TTF'],
['2', '07-09-2020', '8:43:02', '100', 'GGY'],
['3', '07-09-2020', '7:53:08', '120', 'HHJ'],
['4', '07-09-2020', '7:54:01', '160', 'JJH'],
['5', '07-09-2020', '8:30:00', '160', 'RRT'],
['6', '07-09-2020', '10:10:10', '160', 'PPO'],
['7', '07-09-2020', '11:12:11', '100', 'KKG'],
['8', '07-09-2020', '11:31:55', '160', 'PPO']]
```

I really have no clue what is happening and whats going wrong.

Comment: Why 2 rows of `100`? or the car number is `index[4]`?

Comment: @Epsi95, thats just the way it is. That means that vehicle `100` contains 2 components

Comment: Can u use `pandas`?

Comment: No, I prefer doing it inside this loop. Ultimately I want to place them all back in a new list

Comment: The input not clear to me, why 100 `kkg` not there?

Comment: @Epsi95 because the datetime of `100 kkg` is `11:12:11`, the datetime of `100 TTF` and `100 GGY` is `08:43:02`. That is closer to to `chosen_datetime`. You understand it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that you have a `print` command *inside* your loop. Since you won't know which rows have the datetime closest to `chosen_datetime` until *after* you have looped over all the items, this is premature and is a significant cause of your erroneous output.

Secondly, since you're looking for the closest datetime *per vehicle
number* you're going to need some logic to group things by vehicle
number.

One option would be a solution using `itertools.groupby`; another
solution -- that I've implemented here -- would be store results in a
dictionary keyed by the vehicle number.

There are a few comments in the following code, but let me know if
you'd like some additional detail.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta


matched_rows_2 = [
    ['1', '07-09-2020', '8:43:02', '100', 'TTF'],
    ['2', '07-09-2020', '8:43:02', '100', 'GGY'],
    ['3', '07-09-2020', '7:53:08', '120', 'HHJ'],
    ['4', '07-09-2020', '7:54:01', '160', 'JJH'],
    ['5', '07-09-2020', '8:30:00', '160', 'RRT'],
    ['6', '07-09-2020', '10:10:10', '160', 'PPO'],
    ['7', '07-09-2020', '11:12:11', '100', 'KKG'],
    ['8', '07-09-2020', '11:31:55', '160', 'PPO']]

chosen_datetime = datetime.fromisoformat("2020-07-09 08:43:55+00:00")
dts = [
    datetime.strptime(f'{row[1]} {row[2]}', '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S').replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
    for row in matched_rows_2
]

mindelta = defaultdict(lambda: None)
minrows = defaultdict(lambda: None)

# use zip() to combine the timestamps in dts with the
# original data
for ts, row in zip(dts, matched_rows_2):
    # get the absolute difference from chosen_datetime
    delta = abs((ts - chosen_datetime).total_seconds())
    vid = row[3]

    # if it's the closest value for this vid (or if we haven't
    # processed the vid yet), update mindelta[vid] with the current
    # delta and set minrows[vid] to the current row.
    if mindelta[vid] is None or delta < mindelta[vid]:
        mindelta[vid] = delta
        minrows[vid] = [row]

    # if the current delta is equal to the existing closest delta,
    # just append the current row.
    elif delta == mindelta[vid]:
        minrows[vid].append(row)

for vid, rows in minrows.items():
    for row in rows:
        print(row)
```

Running the above program produces the following output:

```
['1', '07-09-2020', '8:43:02', '100', 'TTF']
['2', '07-09-2020', '8:43:02', '100', 'GGY']
['3', '07-09-2020', '7:53:08', '120', 'HHJ']
['5', '07-09-2020', '8:30:00', '160', 'RRT']
```

Comment: can we have a private confersation about this codE?

Comment: We can have a *public* conversation about the code [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230023/how-to-filter-your-list-based-on-datetime).